# Spring Boot : Hibernate CrudRepository with criteria

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using `Spring Boot` and `Hibernate` `JPA`.

I have a `Favorite` table with fields *UserId*, *FavId*, *FavOrder*.

- UserId is unique **user** Id
- FavId is unique Id of **favorite**
- FavOrder is auto generated column with values 1,2,3.. etc and is used to get favorites in descending order to display latest first.

How to implement `CrudRepository`for below scenarios in `Hibernate` + `Spring Boot` :

- Insert only 10 favorites for a user.
- Upon reaching 10 favorites, the oldest needs to be replaced.
- When a Favorite is deleted, how to re-arrange the *FavOrder* from 1 to 10.

Comment: What have you tried? What's the concrete problem you're facing? Where is your code?

Comment: My thought for limiting to 10 favorites is to check number of records of a user while inserting and if it exceeds 10, then check for favorder and replace it. It feel it is not correct approach and wanted to check if some concrete solution is available